# How to query with order by time different

Tags: angularjs, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am having a real-time Firebase with time, value as following, timing is 1 min delay btw each object.

```
  "-LhIaB7SP0y-FLb1xFFx" : {
    "time" : 1560475623,
    "value" : 11.614479842990287
  },
  "-LhIaJ6PjtbX1VHKlwFM" : {
    "time" : 1560475681,
    "value" : 11.642968895431837
  },
  "-LhIaXbX42k8dmApfztL" : {
    "time" : 1560475741,
    "value" : 11.707783121665505
  },
  "-LhIaqgYSpUmKbcH1MTN" : {
    "time" : 1560475802,
    "value" : 11.704004474172576
  },
  "-LhIb-20G9jnx61vNjS-" : {
    "time" : 1560475861,
    "value" : 11.69861155382089
  },
  "-LhIbDdTEdWrhirbjVRa" : {
    "time" : 1560475921,
    "value" : 11.661539551497276
  },
  "-LhIbSGKvS2POggUCots" : {
    "time" : 1560475981,
    "value" : 11.581711077020692
  }
```

I can retrieve data for "time" in order. But I want to filter for every 5 mins, or 1 day, and a week.

```
this.items = this.db.list(`history/data`, ref => ref.orderByChild("time").limitToLast(1000));
```

Is there firebase list filtering for that?

Answer (score 0):

The query model of the Firebase Realtime Database works as follow for your code:

- It orders the child nodes of the reference by the child you indicate.
- It finds the last node in the result, and then returns the 1000 nodes before that.

You can add a condition to your query with `startAt()`, `endAt`, and/or `equalTo`, so make the database start/end at a specific set of child nodes within the range. But there is no way within these conditions to skip child nodes in the middle. Once the database has found a child node to start returning, it will return all child nodes from there on until the conditions are no longer met.

The simplest way I can think of to implement your requirement is to store the data in the aggregation buckets that you want to query on. So if you want to allow reading the data in a way that gives you the first and last item of every week, and the first and last item of every week, you'd store:

```
2019w24_first: "-LhIaB7SP0y-FLb1xFFx",
2019w24_last: "-LhIbSGKvS2POggUCots",
2019m06_first: "-LhIaB7SP0y-FLb1xFFx",
2019m06_last: "-LhIbSGKvS2POggUCots"
```

And then each time when you write the data, you update the relevant aggregates too.

This sounds incredibly inefficient for folks who come from a background with relational/SQL databases, but is actually very common in NoSQL databases. By making your write operations do some extra work, and storing some duplicate data, your read operations becomes massively more scaleable.

For some more information on these types of data modeling choices, I recommend:

- reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)
- watching [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ), which may be for a different Firebase Database, but many of the principles apply equally.